# how to Insert calculate values to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert calculate values to Database.a and b from text field.this is my code.but it doesn't work.please help me

```
<?php
  require('dbconnection.php');
    $a=$_POST['a'];
    $b=$_POST['b'];

    class cal{
   public function insert($a,$b){

    if((($a)&&($b))!="")
    {
     $c=$a*$b;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cropplant (sbetweenQ ,sbetweenC ,sbetweenTC ) VALUES ('$a', '$b', '$c')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$query)
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("DB Update error ! please Re-enter your details.");</script>'; 
            }else
                {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("New value Added Successfuly.");</script>'; 

            }
}else{
    echo"please enter all";
    }}}
    ?>
```

Comment: are u calling function anywhere?

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection. An by open, I mean wide open.

Answer (score 1):

Your function basically does nothing. You fetch two post variables, and define a class. What you need to do is call the function in the class to process the two variables.

Comment: I'm new to PHP can you fix this for me. please.

Comment: My assumption was that is you know how to create a class, you will also know how to call one :-)
If you remove the line starting with 'class' and the one with 'public', and also remove two of the three closing brackets, your code will probably work. Please note the comment of @Wayne above about SQL injection.

Comment: There is a good guide for OO PHP at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762